# How to add existing project (locally in my computer) to a new repository, using vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

i have an existing Java script project on my own laptop, could someone tell me how can i add it to new git hub repository, using vs code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal :

```
git clone REPOSITORY_URL
mv THE_JS_PROJECT_FOLDER REPOSITORY_FOLDER
cd REPOSITORY_FOLDER
git add .
git commit -m  "some message"
git push
```

Comment: Does this actually add a local repo to a *new* GH repo using VScode?

Comment: He didn't say (a local repo) he only said local project.
Also, yes it works with VSCode terminal obviously on MacOS and linux.
For windows he only needs to replace mv with mov.